# Reloading rows makes table "jump" when table scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autoscroll

I've got a table that has some rows that hold a textfield each. When the textfield updates some rows of the table have to update to display some new data. This works fine as long as the table is not scrolled down at all.

However, if the table is scrolled, reloading the rows results in a "jump" animation for the table. My code:

```
formFieldsTable.reloadRows(at: [indexPath,indexPath2], with: .none)
```

Comment: Do you use cells with dynamic height ? Or do you not disable dynamic height cell in iOS 11 ?

Comment: hmm i do return UITableViewAutomaticDimension on heightForRow HOWEVER the height always remains the same, its not like there's actually anything dynamic there, im just using it for convenience.

Comment: Try without it. Return a value in heightForRow and set estimatedRowHeight = 0

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks a lot i should have thought of that. I just imagined that since there's nothing actually dynamic involved it shouldnt happen but apparently not.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48150726/3857555

Comment: @GaétanZ i think you re linking me to my own question.

Comment: Sorry : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48155678/3857555

Answer (score 4):

Per one of the comments above, this fixed the same issue for me:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 75.0
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    formFieldsTable.estimatedRowHeight = 75
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works, but it does not account for dynamic cells